# How to quintile by date group using Percentile in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

Im just wondering if its possible to quintile my data by group in Excel, using the percentile function.

I can quintile my entire data by doing `=MATCH(C2|PERCENTILE(C$2:C$20|{5,4,3,2,1}/5)|-1)` but I want to group it up by date.

e.g of data

```
Date    Team_Id Score
04/02/2019  1   50
04/02/2019  2   58
04/02/2019  3   75
04/02/2019  4   34
04/02/2019  5   52
04/02/2019  6   81
05/02/2019  1   87
05/02/2019  2   75
05/02/2019  3   24
05/02/2019  4   75
05/02/2019  5   11
05/02/2019  6   84
06/02/2019  1   45
06/02/2019  2   67
06/02/2019  3   56
06/02/2019  4   55
06/02/2019  5   61
06/02/2019  6   15
06/02/2019  7   88
```

So basically I want it to be quintiled by Score for each date group, resulting value for each row in Excel should be 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5. Ive been messing around with IF but just dont know where to place it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can tolerate typing **CTL SHFT ENTER** (or at least wait until [Microsoft comes out with their big release](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Excel-Blog/Excel-Dynamic-Array-Improvements/ba-p/332070)) I think this will work

`=MATCH(C4,PERCENTILE(IF($A$4:$A$22=A4,$C$4:$C$22,""),{5,4,3,2,1}/5),-1)`

This is essentially building a conditional array on each row based on the date

Again when entering the formula you have to type ctl SHIFT enter or it will work.

I'm not exactly sure what we're doing here so if this wrong, sorry.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Will this work?

```
=MATCH(C2,PERCENTILE(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1+MATCH($A2,$A$2:$A$20,0),3)&":"&ADDRESS(ROW()+COUNTIF(A3:$A$20,$A2),3)),{5,4,3,2,1}/5),-1)
```

I've defined the range for the percentile calculation using an `Indirect` function where the start and end of the range are found with `Match` and `Countif`, respectively.

Comment: I like that yours doesn't require an array but I think yours operates under the assumption that the dates are always connected. This is probably true in this case, but that's why my answer went the array route.

Any idea what this formula is actually doing...?? I have no clue other than something with fives. ⁉